# Alias name in Delete/Update : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS

Tags: sql-server-2008

How i can use alias name in delete/update statement.
Please see my SP below. it gives error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Market_Delete]    Script Date: 05/22/2015 16:37:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Market_Delete]
(
    @Original_MarketCd char(3)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
DELETE FROM [MKT]  WHERE (([MKT_CD] AS MarketCd = @Original_MarketCd))
GO
```

Comment: `WHERE (([MKT_CD] AS MarketCd = @Original_MarketCd))` here you are checking a column agains variable..then how can u alias a column using AS inside where clause?

Comment: What's the context?  I've never heard of someone even needing to alias a field in a simple delete statement before.  Is the real statement more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you need to give alias to the table for Delete statement

Try this

```
DELETE From MarketCd
FROM [MKT] AS MarketCd WHERE ([MKT_CD]   = @Original_MarketCd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm interpreting what you say correctly, what you want is to be able to refer to fields by aliases, while performing an update or delete.

You could try this:

```
 ;
 WITH  Market
 AS   (
     SELECT    MarketCd = [MKT_CD]
     FROM      [MKT]
 )
 DELETE  Market
 FROM    Market
 WHERE   MarketCd = @Original_MarketCd
```

You'd do something similar for an update:

```
 ;
 WITH  Market
 AS   (
     SELECT    MarketCd = [MKT_CD]
     FROM      [MKT]
 )
 UPDATE  Market
    SET  MarketCd = @New_MarketCd
 WHERE   MarketCd = @Old_MarketCd
```

What I'm doing there is using a Common Table Expression (CTE) to alias the table and the field, and then performing the `DELETE` or `UPDATE` using the preferred aliases.